# Getting error "Uncaught TypeError: t.addLayer is not a function" in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, typeerror

When running the following script, I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: t.addLayer is not a function
at e.addTo (Layer.js:52:7)
    at addDataToMap (index.php:56)
    at xhrPoints.onreadystatechange (index.php:76)
```

I can't find out why this error occurs and what the solution is.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha256-p4NxAoJBhIIN+hmNHrzRCf9tD/miZyoHS5obTRR9BMY" crossorigin="" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-20nQCchB9co0qIjJZRGuk2/Z9VM+kNiyxNV1lvTlZBo=" crossorigin=""></script>

  <style>
    .leaflet-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .leaflet-control-layers {
      text-align: left;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id='map'></div>

  <script>

    //CartoDB Toner tiles attribution and URL
    var cartoDBURL = 'https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png';
    var cartoDBAttrib = '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a>';

    var cartodbMap = L.tileLayer(cartoDBURL, {
      attribution: cartoDBAttrib,
    });

    // Map creation
    var map = L.map('map', {
      layers: [cartodbMap]
    }).setView([52.53, 13.2], 13); // Berlin

    var points;
    var pointLayer;
    var track;
    var trackLayer;

    function loadData() {
      //load points data
      var xhrPoints = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhrPoints.open('GET', 'http://91.64.76.8/radmonitor/geojson_location.php?t=' + new Date().getTime(), true);
      xhrPoints.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhrPoints.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhrPoints.status === 200) {
          points = JSON.parse(xhrPoints.responseText);
          if (pointLayer) {
            map.removeLayer(pointLayer);
          }
          addDataToMap();
        }
      };
      xhrPoints.send();
    }

    // Führe loadData() beim ersten Aufruf der Seite direkt aus
    loadData();
    setInterval(loadData, 5000);

    // Punkt Style
    var locationStyle = {
      radius: 6,
      fillColor: "#0198E1",
      color: "#ffffff",
      weight: 2,
      opacity: 1,
      fillOpacity: 1
    };

    function addDataToMap() {
      pointLayer = L.geoJSON(points, {
        pointToLayer: function createCircleMarker(feature, latlng) {
          return L.circleMarker(latlng, locationStyle);
        }
      }).addTo(map);
    }
    
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you check that you are getting valid data from server? For me code works without any problems, just had to use proxy to retrieve data to avoid CORS error.